# No output - scraping using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image]When I try to scrape data with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests
import re
start_url = requests.get('http://www.indiaproperty.com/chennai-property-search-allresidential-properties-for-sale-in-velachery-results')
soup = BeautifulSoup(start_url.content)
properties = soup.findAll('a',{'class':'paddl10'})
for eachproperty in properties:
 print eachproperty['href']
```

I do not see any output. It does not give any error also. I checked if it is getting redirected using following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.indiaproperty.com/chennai-property-search-allresidential-properties-for-sale-in-velachery-results')
response.url
```

Then it also shows nothing and no error either.

Comment: The page you link to has **no** links with class `paddl10`.

Comment: Please check the picture I have added

Comment: Perhaps JavaScript alters the page after loading, but the URL you load does **not** have that class on any `<a>` link. `{c for a in soup.find_all('a') for c in a.attrs.get('class', [])}` gives me `set(['', 'tab-act', 'srh-grid-off', 'selected', 'srh-list-on', 'blueBtn', 'srh-flr-rt-nx', 'srh-flr-rt', 'pntr'])`.

Comment: The parent `<div id="IP4">` is not present either; the page is using dynamic content.

Comment: Yes. I noticed it. But when I inspected that element, I could see the class and when I view source of the page, I dont find any. That muddled me.

Comment: So what is the best way to scrape such websites?

Comment: The page loads additional data from `http://www.indiaproperty.com/ajax/ajaxlocality.php?defaultallloaclity=defaultallloaclity&v=3156&selloc=29975`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37386/discussion-between-venky-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: @Venky I could help perhaps if you show you goal. What do you want to get from this page?

Comment: I am trying to scrape Title,Price,Per Sq.Ft price, Property Id, Created Date, Details from view details and Contact details, of every project from the above mentioned URL.